# can call function in model from controller with sails framework?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have user model and user Controller that I have generate from sails command. I just want call function that I created on model from controller like:

// user model

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
     name: {
       type: 'string',
       required: true
     }
  },
 CallUserFunction: function(){
   //some code goes here.
 }
}
```

// userController

```
module.exports = {
   create: function(req, res){
      User.CallUserFunction();//can i call function in user Model like this? 
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define instance methods for models with sails.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720846/how-to-define-instance-methods-for-models-with-sails-js)

Comment: If your question is, "can I defined a class method in my model", then the answer is "yes".  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't an instance method. Instead of calling just `User.CallUserFunction()` you need to do something like this:

### User Model

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
     name: {
       type: 'string',
       required: true
     }
  },
 CallUserFunction: function(){
   //some code goes here.
 }
}
```

### User Controller

```
module.exports = {
   create: function(req, res){
      sails.models.user.CallUserFunction();//can i call function in user Model like this? 
  }
}
```

**edit:** forgive any typo's as i'm not in front of my dev workstation to test this, i do know its very close to that syntax of `sails.models` though.

Comment: Hi @gorelative but how can I have a returned value from MyUsers.myCollectionMethod(); when I call this from a Controller like var tmpResult = MyUsers.myCollectionMethod();